# paste image from chemdraw to word not possible

Tags: clipboard

When copy image of CHEMDRAW  professional 2020 to  Office Word 2019 there is an error as below

word encountered a problem

There is an option for help that describe the problem as below but non of them is for my pc

There is a problem saving the file.
Usually this is because the disk or floppy disk is too small for the file or is full, RAM memory is low, or there is a permission problem with the drive the file is being saved to.
If the amount of disk space for a paging file is low, save the file to another drive. If the RAM memory is low, increase available RAM. If permissions to the drive do not allow you to save to that drive, save the file to another drive or request permissions from the administrator to save files to the drive.
Note   This error can also occur if the computer is running a version of antivirus software that is incompatible with the Microsoft Office or must be updated.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD as administrator
then run "start winword /safe"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).